# SQL Query to show the same data but based on different dates in the same view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an SQL query that I use to show the # of work orders created by day within a designated date range. It works well when I query a single date range, such as 3/1/2016 to 3/31/2016.

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dateCreated), 0) the_date,
COUNT(*) work_order_count
FROM WorkOrder
where active = 1 and
dateCreated >= '3/1/2016' and
dateCreated <= '3/31/2016 23:59:59'
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dateCreated), 0)
order by 1;
```

I want to take this same query a step further so that I can query the same data but show results for multiple date ranges. My specific purpose is to show data side-by-side for previous year comparison. Ideally I want to show the # of work orders created for 3/1-3/31 in 2014, 2015 and 2016, but all within the same view/result.

Is this possible? I've looked into joins but they appear to be when you are using different tables, not the same one.

Comment: create a stored procedure that accepts your start/end dates as parameters.  Depending on how creative you want to get with the procedure, you should easily be able to return 3 data sets by doing some simple date math with sql's `dateadd()` function.

Comment: Self Joins can be done using subqueries on the same table, e.g.: `INNER JOIN (Select <your field list> from WorkOrder where <your date criteria>) as WorkOrderAlias1 on WorkOrderAlias1.somejoinfield = WorkOrder.somejoinfield`

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation (or a pivot):

```
SELECT CAST(dateCreated as DATE) as the_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(dateCreated) = 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_2014,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(dateCreated) = 2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_2015,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(dateCreated) = 2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt_2016
FROM WorkOrder
WHERE active = 1 and
      MONTH(dateCreated) = 3 and
      YEAR(dateCreated) in (2014, 2015, 2016)
GROUP BY CAST(dateCreated as DATE)
ORDER BY the_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot table:

```
;with cte1 as (
  select dateCreated, datepart(year, dateCreated) as Y
  from WorkOrder
  where datepart(month, dateCreated) = 3 and datepart(day, dateCreated) between 5 and 25
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1
  PIVOT
  (
    count(dateCreated)
    FOR Y in ([2014], [2015], [2016])
  ) as pv
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN dateCreated BETWEEN '3/1/2014' AND '3/31/2014 23:59:59'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS March2014,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN dateCreated BETWEEN '3/1/2015' AND '3/31/2015 23:59:59'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS March2015,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN dateCreated BETWEEN '3/1/2016' AND '3/31/2016 23:59:59'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS March2016
FROM WorkOrder
WHERE active = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT datepart(dd, 'yyyy'), datepart(dd, 'MM'), datepart(dd, 'dd'),
       COUNT(*) work_order_count
FROM WorkOrder
where active = 1 
  and dateCreated >=  '3/1/2016' 
  and dateCreated <   '4/1/2020' 
GROUP BY datepart(dd, 'yyyy'), datepart(dd, 'MM'), datepart(dd, 'dd')     
order by datepart(dd, 'yyyy'), datepart(dd, 'MM'), datepart(dd, 'dd');
```